# Uploading file with JavaScript Youtube API - MediaUploader is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm working on a web app, trying to enable sharing a video on Youtube, essentially adding an "Upload to youtube" button. I'm trying to use the Youtube Data API for JavaScript, following this example https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#upload_video.

My code is the same as in the example. All was going well until I got an error "MediaUploader is not defined" from this line of code:

```
var uploader = new MediaUploader({
```

The MediaUploader class doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in the example code.

I've searched far and wide through Google API docs and JS ref, but the only mention of a MediaUploader class I found is in the context of WordPress, PHP or Python.

Please help - what is MediaUploader in the context of JavaScript/Google API and where can I find documentation on it?

Comment: had the same problem over here !!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, got back to this task & finally found the answer. The MediaUploader class is defined in https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/cors_upload.js.

Dear Google/Youtube docs maintenance people, if you ever read this please add this code sample to the official docs on resumable upload using JavaScript! It will save a world of pain.

Comment: well done for finding that ! I was looking for this file and tried to run without cors...alas is needed.